# unable to load two table views in one view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Error:- use of un declared identifier cell.

unable to load two custom cells in one view controller.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == tableView_grantRecordAccess)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_grantRecordAccess dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EHSRecordAccessGrantCell"];

           if (cell == nil) {

               // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.

                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EHSRecordAccessGrantCell" owner:self options:nil];

                // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).

                cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

            }

        return cell;

    }

 else if (tableView == tableView_accessRecordRequest)  {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_accessRecordRequest dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EHSAccessRecordCell"];

        if (cell == nil) {

            // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EHSAccessRecordCell" owner:self options:nil];

            // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).

            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
            }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: check cell identifier in XIB.

Comment: in else if condition we are getting error use of undeclared identifier cell

Comment: A closing bracklet is misplaced ("}") in the `else if` condition when you return cell, it's not defined. Indent correctly your code, you'll see. It should be after `return cell;` instead of before.

Answer (score 1):

This is scope issue of cell reference, if you will make reference of cell at first line of method and then use that reference only in both condition then it will work.

Comment: but the first condition is executing else if condition not executing ,i would like load two table views at once help me

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
      UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
      if (tableView == tableView_grantRecordAccess)
      {
         cell = [tableView_grantRecordAccess dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EHSRecordAccessGrantCell"];

         if (cell == nil) {

           // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EHSRecordAccessGrantCell" owner:self options:nil];

            // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).

            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

        }

      return cell;

}
else if (tableView == tableView_accessRecordRequest)  {

    cell = [tableView_accessRecordRequest dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EHSAccessRecordCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EHSAccessRecordCell" owner:self options:nil];

        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).

        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
  }
  return cell;

}
```

Comment: we are unable to load second table view else if condition not executing.i would like to load two table views at once.

Answer (score 1):

add this line above if condition respectively 
//if (cell == nil) { ...
}

//For first table condition

```
if (![cell isKindOfClass:[EHSRecordAccessGrantCell
 class]])cell = nil;
```

//For second table condition

```
if (![cell isKindOfClass:[EHSAccessRecordCell
 class]])cell = nil;
```

crash because of you have register both cell to table and whenever it comes to second one the cell already have the reference of the second one cell that is differet typeof

Comment: We are getting an error use of undeclared EHSAccessRecordCell

Answer (score 0):

Check in your storyboard for the right cell identifier.

Select both of your table's prototype cell's identifier in identity inspector.

Looking at your error statement, I can assume- You may have forgotten to assign the identifier to your cell or you are using wrong identifier(may be a spelling mistake) in your code(cellForRowAtIndexPath method).